# Why is RequireJS not loading more than once a module I require multiple times?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

When there are two file import same module, it seems to share the same resource, like this:

**main.js:**

```
require(['cmdA', 'cmdB'], function(cmdA, cmdB){

})
```

**cmdA.js:**

```
define(function(require, exports){
    console.log('require: cmdA');
    var body = require('body');
});
```

**cmdB.js:**

```
define(function(require, exports){
    console.log('require: cmdB');
    var body = require('body');
});
```

**result:**

```
require body 
require: cmdA 
require: cmdB
```

So why not :

```
require body
require: cmdA
require body
require: cmdB
```

I think **body.js** is required twice，so console outputs body twice. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default RequireJS treats modules as singletons. Once RequireJS does it's name resolution and finds that you want module `X` then if you require it once, twice, three million times, you'll always get the same module object. The first time the module is required, it is created, and then the next time it is required again, you get the same module as what was returned the first time. The callback you give to `define` is called once, and only once.

If you use [`requirejs.undef`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef), you could trick RequireJS into giving you multiple copies of a module but this is not the basic usage.

Comment: But when I change cmdA.js and cmdB.js like this:  


`

define(function(require, exports){
 console.log('require: cmdA');
 var foo = function(){
  var body = require('body');
 }
});
define(function(require, exports){
 console.log('require: cmdB');
 // var body = require('body');
});
`

why result like this:


`
require: cmdB 
require body 
require: cmdA 
`

Comment: In your new `cmdA.js` RequireJS searches at all the `require` calls that have a single argument which is a string and loads the modules required by these `require` calls *before* it starts executing the callback you give to `define`. For the details of how this works, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396468/requirejs-what-is-the-difference-between-these-methods-of-establishing-module-r/22403087#22403087) and the answer I wrote.